# Spring & Tika integration: is my approach thread-safe?

Tags: spring, thread-safety, apache-tika

I'm interested in Spring & Apache Tika integration.
Is this approach thread-safe?

```
<bean id="tika" class="org.apache.tika.Tika"/>
```

Can I safely call `detect()` method from different threads?

Are there any Spring-Tika integration patterns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to this
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.tika.user/677

and this

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-15824

and this

http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/99aTkiOCyApHaqASS5CS

it would suggest yes.

Though there have been bugs with the thread safety

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-599